# Representing two properties/features with one observation

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

Recently, I went through the blog of [Markus Stocker](http://markusstocker.com/sensor-observations/) where he explains nicely how to represent sensor observations while using [observation](http://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/ssn/wiki/SSN_Observation) module of [SSN](http://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/ssn/XGR-ssn-20110628/) Ontology. I understood his explanations fully but one thing I found redundant to represent two features (here CO2 and H20 concentrations as shown in below table) of a 
row with two separate observations as shown in rdf file at [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u7odxyk9slbj1hu/observations.rdf?dl=0).

[image: img]

I am trying to represent these two features with one observation within rdf file.This will reduce the size of rdf file and remove redundancy.

In other words how can I replace

```xml
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://envi.uef.fi/saicos#o1">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#Observation"/>
<ssn:featureOfInterest rdf:resource="http://envi.uef.fi/saicos#ambientAir"/>
<ssn:observedPropertyrdf:resource="http://envi.uef.fi/saicos#massFractionCO2"/>
<ssn:observationResultTime rdf:resource="http://envi.uef.fi/saicos#rt1"/>
<ssn:observationResult rdf:resource="http://envi.uef.fi/saicos#so1"/>
<ssn:observedBy rdf:resource="http://envi.uef.fi/saicos#theLinnansuoLI-7500"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

and

```xml
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://envi.uef.fi/saicos#o2">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#Observation"/>
<ssn:featureOfInterest rdf:resource="http://envi.uef.fi/saicos#ambientAir"/>
<ssn:observedProperty rdf:resource="http://envi.uef.fi/saicos#massFractionH2O"/>
<ssn:observationResultTime rdf:resource="http://envi.uef.fi/saicos#rt2"/>
<ssn:observationResult rdf:resource="http://envi.uef.fi/saicos#so2"/>
<ssn:observedBy rdf:resource="http://envi.uef.fi/saicos#theLinnansuoLI-7500"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

with

```xml
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.exampleMarkusStocker.com#ob1">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#Observation"/>
<ssn:observationResult rdf:resource="http://www.exampleMarkusStocker.com#S01"/>
<ssn:observationResult rdf:resource="http://www.exampleMarkusStocker.com#S012"/>
<ssn:featureOfInterest rdf:resource="http://www.exampleMarkusStocker.com#ambientAir"/>
<ssn:observedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.exampleMarkusStocker.com#massFractionCo2"/>
<ssn:observedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.exampleMarkusStocker.com#massFractionH2o"/>
<ssn:observationResultTime rdf:resource="http://www.exampleMarkusStocker.com#rt1"/>
<ssn:observedBy rdf:resource="http://www.exampleMarkusStocker.com#theLinnansuoLI-7500"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

This will definitely remove some redundant statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the approach is that you don't know which observation result (and value) relates to which property in the observation. For more discussion about this issue, you may want to read the [*Multiple values in one observation*](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-ssn/2014Apr/0000.html) thread from the public-xg-ssn@w3.org mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to thread. I understood that it unnecessary introduce ambiguities.

Answer (score 2):

If you do this (trimmed):

```xml
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.exampleMarkusStocker.com#ob1">
  <ssn:observationResult rdf:resource="http://www.exampleMarkusStocker.com#S01"/>
  <ssn:observationResult rdf:resource="http://www.exampleMarkusStocker.com#S012"/>
  <ssn:observedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.exampleMarkusStocker.com#massFractionCo2"/>
  <ssn:observedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.exampleMarkusStocker.com#massFractionH2o"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

then you have four triples.  You have

```
:obj1 ssn:observationResult :S01, :S012 ;
      ssn:observedProperty :massFractionC02, :massFractionH2o .
```

But how will you know whether :S01 is supposed to fit with :massFractionCo2 or :massFractionH2o?  How will you know whether :S012 is supposed to fit with :massFractionCo2 or :massFractionH2o?  You can't do it based on any kind of order, since an RDF graph is a *set* of triples;  there's no order (even though any textual representation will obviously have to write the triples in some order).

Doing this doesn't remove any redundancies,  it just introduces ambiguities.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I understood it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a proposal https://w3c.github.io/sdw/proposals/ssn-extensions/ that addresses this question: you make `ssn-ext:ObservationCollection` and fixes some of the attributes, and holds `ssn:Observation`s that vary the remaining attributes and the results.

This is completely analogous to using `qb:Slice` to reduce data in the CUBE ontology.

(I think the above uses OldSSN while ssn-ext relates to the new SSN.)