# Modelling highly redundant subjects in RDF

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, json-ld

## Problem description

I have multiple subjects in the knowledge graph, that are not identical, but highly similar. I want to:

1. model the redundancy only once to optimize the size of the serialized graph.
2. If possible also keep the number of (asserted and inferred) triples low, to keep the memory footprint low.

Example in Turtle:

```
:subject1 ex:comProp1 ex:comValue1;
          ex:comProp2 ex:comValue2;
          ex:comProp3 ex:comValue3;
          # ...
          ex:comProp100 ex:comValue100;
          ex:difProp ex:difValue1.
          
:subject2 ex:comProp1 ex:comValue1;
          ex:comProp2 ex:comValue2;
          ex:comProp3 ex:comValue3;
          # ...
          ex:comProp100 ex:comValue100;
          ex:difProp ex:difValue2.
```

My main question is how to represent this common part only once and refer to it from multiple places.

Below I posted some solution ideas to develop to a full solution or maybe elicit another idea.

## Specific context

I think this problem could occur in several domains, my specific context is in the [TD ontology](https://www.w3.org/2019/wot/td). I have multiple PropertyAffordance instances which share the same schema, but have different protocol bindings due to different addresses. Since all properties are gathered on one subject, I need a mechanism to refer to common properties to avoid the size explosion of the serialized data.

## Solution ideas

### A: Something like Javascript's spread operator

I want to model the reoccurring part only once and refer to it, as can be done in Javascript with the spread operator:

```js
const comPart = {comProp1: comValue1, comProp2: comValue:2 /* etc. */}
const subject1 = {...comPart1, difProp: difValue1}
const subject2 = {...comPart1, difProp: difValue2}
```

In RDF:

```
:comPart  ex:comProp1 ex:comValue1;
          ex:comProp2 ex:comValue2;
          ex:comProp3 ex:comValue3;
          # ...
          ex:comProp100 ex:comValue100.

:subject1 rdf:spread :comPart;
          ex:difProp1 ex:difValue1 .

:subject2 rdf:spread :comPart;
          ex:difProp ex:difValue2 .
```

Is there something similar to `rdf:spread` in RDF?

### B: Restriction classes

Using `owl:Restriction` classes, I can define a class for the common part, which has lots of `owl:hasValue` restrictions for every common property. And each subject would refer to this class via `rdf:type`, inheriting all restrictions.

This would work for serialization and keeping the number of asserted triples low, but:

1. the syntax for defining restrictions is quite cumbersome
2. using types and inheritance to do this feels heavy-handed for me.

### C: JSON-LD context definition

If not possible to do this in RDF, it would also be OK to define a context definition for the common part in JSON-LD. This would reduce the size of the serialized graph, but the number of asserted triples would be the same.

I haven't worked out the details for this approach yet.

### D: Reification

Some way to take over reified common statements to subjects? Also haven't worked out the details yet.

## References

I found a similar need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160865/representing-two-properties-features-with-one-observation) There the last proposed solution is to extend the ontology, so that the common part is fully identical, and can be represented by a single subject. This doesn't work for me, as I cannot change the involved ontologies.

Comment: As written, this question is really too broad and vague to be answerable - you essentially have four or five different questions in here. Can you narrow it down to a specific question? Have a look at [ask].

Comment: To answer one of your questions briefly: there is no such thing as `rdf:spread` in RDF, but of course nothing stops you from introducing it yourself. I would name it differently though, think about it in terms of the captured knowledge that the collection of common properties represents, rather than in terms of programming operators.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and answer. There is actually only one main question as laid out in the problem description. The other questions are just details related to a solution idea.

About rdf:spread, yes I would also name it differently. It's a very specific word from Javascript world. But, if I introduce it, none of the existing tools would support it. So I'd like an already available solution.